# Reference to a non-const object cannot be initialized with an r-value of that object

Tags: c++

I create an object and try to pass that object through multiple function by reference

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
#include "DBMS.h"
using namespace std;

void Home(DBMS &);
int main()
{
    DBMS dbms();
    Home(dbms); // this is where the error is 
    return 0;
}

void Home(DBMS &dbms)
{
    string dbName;
    dbms.addDatabase(dbName);
}
```

and this is DBMS.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Database.h"
using namespace std;

class DBMS
{
public:
    DBMS();

    void addDatabase(string);
    Database& getDatabase(string);
    Database& getDatabaseByIndex(int);
    int getDatabaseIndex(string);
    void removeDatabase(string);
    int size();
    ~DBMS();

private:
    vector <Database> dbList;
    string error;
};

DBMS::DBMS()
{
}



void DBMS::addDatabase(string tbNames)
{
    vector<string> TB_Names = tokenize(tbNames);
    int size = TB_Names.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (getDatabaseIndex(TB_Names[i]) == -1)
        {
            Database tb(TB_Names[i]);
            dbList.push_back(tb);
        }
        else
            throw "Already esited Database with given name";
    }
}

Database& DBMS::getDatabase(string tbName)
{
    int i;
    int size = dbList.size();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (dbList[i].getName() == tbName)
            return dbList[i];
    }

    throw invalid_argument("Database not found");

}

Database& DBMS::getDatabaseByIndex(int index)
{
    return dbList[index];
}

void DBMS::removeDatabase(string TB_Name)
{
    int i;
    int size = dbList.size();
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (dbList[i].getName() == TB_Name)
        {
            dbList.erase(dbList.begin() + i);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == size)
        throw invalid_argument("Field not found");


}

int DBMS::getDatabaseIndex(string TB_Name)
{
    int size = dbList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (dbList[i].getName() == TB_Name)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

int DBMS::size()
{
    return dbList.size();
}
DBMS::~DBMS()
{
}
```

(Database type is just another class i create. Nothing special about it. Don't worry about it (Unless you think I have to))
The error statement is : >a reference of type "DBMS &" (a non-const-qualified) cannot be initialized with an value of "DBMS()"
I found a suggestion that i should fix `void Home(DBMS &dbms)` to `void Home(const DBMS &dbms)`
but if i do that, i can't use addDatabase() function
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This declaration

```
DBMS dbms();
```

is a vexing parse. You are not declaring a variable named `dbms`, but instead you are actually declaring a function named `dbms` that takes no arguments, and returns a `DBMS`. Passing this object to a function expecting a `DBMS` object will not work.

You can fix this with:

```
DBMS dbms{};
```

Comment: Or just `DBMS dbms;`

Comment: @user253751 Well, yes, in this case, but there are many ways to initialize a variable, and I want to show just one, so I picked uniform initialization.

Comment: I see it now, feel lil bit silly of myself. Thank you guys

Comment: @HoàngTháiVương No worries, that's why it's vexing :) Consider accepting the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: @cigien ... also known as "not-so-uniform" initialization :)

Comment: @C.M. Sure, it's not perfect. But are you actually suggesting `DBMS dbms;` instead, or something else entirely?

Comment: [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis covers all the gloriously different ways one can initialize in C++.  (It's an hour long.  And goes into detail.)

Comment: @Eljay This whole comment section is getting off-topic. Yes, there are many ways to initialize. Is the version in my answer problematic in any way? I don't want to show multiple options without a good reason.